# R CMD BATCH output

Tags: r, batch-processing

is there a way to give the same name of the R script to the pdf produced using R CMD BATCH such as for the .Rout file?

This is the default:

```
:~$ R CMD BATCH my_script.R
:~$ ls
my_script.R
my_script.Rout
Rplots.pdf
```

So to change Rplots.pdf into my_scripts.pdf

**EDIT**
 The code for my_script.R

```
x <- c(1:5); y <- x # create some data
par(pch=22, col="red") # plotting symbol and color
par(mfrow=c(2,4)) # all plots on one page
opts = c("p","l","o","b","c","s","S","h")
for(i in 1:length(opts)){
  heading = paste("type=",opts[i])
  plot(x, y, type="n", main=heading)
  lines(x, y, type=opts[i])
}
```

Comment: Produce some code in `my_script.R`. I've done some searching and have a candidate solution but would like to test before posting.

Comment: Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 2):

You can name your PDF-file direct in the R-code

```
 pdf(file = "my_script.pdf")
 plot(data)
 dev.off()
```

If you do not give a file name in the function `pdf()`then the name is (by default) `Rplots.pdf`

Comment: I have several plot so I would like to not call each plot using pdf() from within the R script

Comment: I don't understand this. How are you creating your PDFs otherwise in the script?

Comment: from terminal I invoke R CMD BATCH my_script.R and it produce my_script.Rout and a file named RPlots.pdf with all the figures created by each plot() call present in the script

Comment: Ok, I see. But so you can once write `pdf("my_script.pdf")` before the first plot and `dev.off()` after the last plot ... so you only have to involve 2 lines!

Comment: Ok this could be the trick but I can't believe there is not an option to perform this job

Comment: There is an option to rename the outfile, but this doesn't influence the .pdf plot, I have tried this. 
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/BATCH.html

Comment: I saw, I have already tried it but it only affect the Rout file

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the command line arguments and the third one will be the file name of the batch file so you can save a pdf file by that name.

```
x <- c(1:5); y <- x # create some data
args <- commandArgs()
pdf( paste0( sub("[.]R", "", args[3]), ".pdf") )
# Need to have the par-arguments supplied after `pdf()` is opened
par(pch=22, col="red") # plotting symbol and color
par(mfrow=c(2,4)) # all plots on one page
opts = c("p","l","o","b","c","s","S","h")

for(i in 1:length(opts)){
  heading = paste("type=",opts[i])
    plot(x, y, type="n", main=heading  )
    lines(x, y, type=opts[i] )

}
 dev.off()
```

I did try to send a "file" argument to the `plot` device, since I thought that it would be passed along by the "dots"-mechanism to the pdf function, but it failed. (Might have worked if only one plot call were being made.) You could on the other hand define an environment variable R_DEFAULT_DEVICE that would be function code that would incorporate this strategy. See `?options` in the grDevices Section.